# show/hide a div on hover and hover out

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I would like to show and hide a div during hover and hover out.

here's what I've done lately.

css

```js
$("#menu").hover(function() {
  $('.flyout').removeClass('hidden');
}, function() {
  $('.flyout').addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.flyout {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 450px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="margint10 round-border">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="" id="menu_link" /></a>
</div>
<div class="flyout hidden">&nbsp;</div>
```

My problem is that when I hover on the menu id, the flyout div is blinking.
why is that?

Comment: When I tried it with Firefox it worked (no blinking): http://jsfiddle.net/dxWXU/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

May be there no need for JS. You can achieve this with css also. Write like this:

```css
.flyout {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 450px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: none;
}
#menu:hover + .flyout {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: can you explain  + .flyout{ ?

Comment: it's called Adjacent sibling combinator. For more read this http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/adjacent

Comment: display:inline-block to get the element to appear in flow order.

Answer (score 36):

Why not just use `.show()/.hide()` instead?

```
$("#menu").hover(function(){
    $('.flyout').show();
},function(){
    $('.flyout').hide();
});
```

Comment: @nnnnnn show/hide use `display` instead of `visibility`, the difference is `visibility` will still take hold place while `display` doesn't. The op code may be affected by other of his html code.

Comment: Sure, I understand the difference between `display` and `visibility` - I meant why would the OP's code cause any blinking but yours wouldn't? (I prefer your solution, but I don't see why it would help.)

Answer (score 16):

Here are different method of doing this. And i found your code is even working fine.

Your code: http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/

Jquery toggle class demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/2/

Jquery fade toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/3/

Jquery slide toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/4/

And you can do this with CSS as answered by **Sandeep**

Answer (score 3):

I found using css opacity is better for a simple show/hide hover, and you can add [css3](http://css3generator.com/) transitions to make a nice finished hover effect. The transitions will just be dropped by older IE browsers, so it degrades gracefully to.

#### JS fiddle Demo

### CSS

```
#stuff {
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#hover {
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#hover:hover + #stuff {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="hover">Hover</div>
<div id="stuff">stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var IdAry=['reports1'];
    window.onload=function() {
     for (var zxc0=0;zxc0<IdAry.length;zxc0++){
      var el=document.getElementById(IdAry[zxc0]);
      if (el){
       el.onmouseover=function() {
         changeText(this,'hide','show')
        }
       el.onmouseout=function() {
         changeText(this,'show','hide');
        }
      }
     }
    }
    function changeText(obj,cl1,cl2) {
       obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].className=cl1;
       obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[1].className=cl2;
    }
</script>
```

ur html should look like this

```
<p id="reports1">
                <span id="span1">Test Content</span>
                <span class="hide">

                    <br /> <br /> This is the content that appears when u hover on the it
                </span>
            </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to show the div, and set it at wherever your mouse is:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="trigger">
      <h1>Hover me!</h1>
      <p>Ill show you wonderful things</p>
    </div>
    <div id="secret">
     shhhh
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

styles:

```
#trigger {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#secret {
  display:none;
  top:0;  
  position:absolute;
  background: grey;
  color:white;
  width: 50%;
}
```

js:

```
$("#trigger").hover(function(e){
    $("#secret").show().css('top', e.pageY + "px").css('left', e.pageX + "px");
  },function(e){
    $("#secret").hide()
})
```

You can find the example here
Cheers!
http://plnkr.co/edit/LAhs8X9F8N3ft7qFvjzy?p=preview