# Best way to make toggle effect on column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four columns that I want to toggle on hover.

Each column will have default content (visible when the page loads)
and content that will only show when the mouse hovers over the column.

I want the on-hover content to show with a smooth toggle effect (sliding down)

Just to make sure we're on the right track, I don't need to know how to do this.
I know how, what I need to know is the "best" way to do this.

Comment: using jquery could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to work with the "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" events.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('IDOfTheElement').onmouseover = function() {
    // Whatever your hover code goes here
    document.getElementById('IDOfElementYouWantToShow').style.display = "block";
});

document.getElementById('IDOfTheElement').onmouseout = function() {
    // Exit hover code goes here
    document.getElementById('IDOfElementYouWantToHide').style.display = "none";
});
```

jQuery has a nice way of dealing with this:

```
$('#IDOfTheElement').on('mouseover', function() {
    // Whatever your hover code goes here
    $('#IDOfElementYouWantToShow').show();
    // Or you can
    $('#IDOfElementYouWantToShow').fadeIn("slow", function() {
        alert('Fading in!');
    });
});

$('#IDOfTheElement').on('mouseout', function() {
    // Exit hover code goes here
    $('#IDOfElementYouWantToHide').hide();
    // Or you can
    $('#IDOfElementYouWantToShow').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        alert('Fading out!');
    });
});
```

Note that some browsers may have issues with show() and hide(), so you may need to use `document.getElementById('ID').style.display = 'block';` or `document.getElementById('ID').style.display = 'none';`.

Comment: Thanks, but do you think there is a way to do this without making a function for every column? Is there some way to do this using just one function?

Comment: you can attach the function to all columns and have it use the id/class to determine which column to show/hide.

Comment: Yes, you can! One way is to add a name attribute to all your columns. For example: <div name="foo"></div>, and I can just say $('div[name="foo"]').on('mouseover',...etc. Saves you time.

Comment: Alright, thank you everybody for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the tag you picked for your question, following is a good solution that olny requires **JQuery** (no **CSS** is involved). It's actually pretty easy using the `hover()` and `toggle()` functions.

```
$('tbody.restricted').hide();

$('table').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('tbody.restricted').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

There's a little more complex challenge that is introduced by your will to animate multiple rows as a block. A solution I find suitable for that purpose is to encapsulate (dynamically or not) the rows you want to animate as a whole within a `tbody` that will be displayed as a `block` with **CSS**.

```
tbody {
    display:block;
}
```

N.B.I went that way because of the usage of a table (columns was mentionned), but you could always design this solution without using tables and only markups displayed as blocks (div by default). This wouldn't require the previous **CSS** alteration.

See this fully functional **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueLn2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to just copy some other code, i think this jsfiddle link would solve your problem nicely.

http://jsfiddle.net/NKC2j/2/

```
$("#menu").hover(function(){
    $('.flyout').slideToggle();
});
```

For performance you would need to toggle a CSS class, otherwise you will need to traverse your DOM a few times to show/hide elements

This is the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114735/1231079