# Cannot get hide/show on mouseover to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I've been trying various things and looking on this site for answers. For some reason none of my tactics are working. I want to make the paragraph in the "topb" section to come up when I hover over the a link with the class of "top" and then disappear when I leave it. I can't, however, get div to even show up on a mouseover. Any suggestions? Thank you.

```js
var num1 = document.getElementByClassName("top");
num1.onmouseover(function() {
var changeIt = getElementByClassName("topb");
if (changeIt.style.visibility === "hidden") {
changeIt.style.visibility = "visible";
}else {
changeIt.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
.topb {
    position:absolute;
    top:140px;
    left:420px;
    color:black;
    border:2px solid black;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class = "sidebar">
<li> <a class="top" href= "filename.html"> A </a>`enter code </li>  
<li> <a class="second" href= "filename.html"> B </a> </li>
<li> <a class="third" href= "filename.html"> C </a></li>
<li> <a class="fourth" href= "filename.html"> D </a></li>
<li> <a class="bottom" href= "filename.html"> E </a></li>
</ul> 

<div class="topb">
<p> sample of application here </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the error console? There are syntax and other errors in your javascript.

Comment: No, I haven't, how do you do that? Do I need to download an interpreter or something?

Comment: I found one and fixed it to this: var num1 = document.getElementByClassName("top");
    num1.onmouseover(function() {
    var changeIt = getElementByClassName("topb");
    if (changeIt.style.visibility === "hidden") {
 changeIt.style.visibility = "visible";
 }else {
 changeIt.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }});

Comment: Almost all browsers have a developer console that shows errors. Google will help you out.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Should it work after syntax fixes or do you see other issues? Changing to above, the code still wasn't working.

Comment: Not sure. One other thing you can do is post the code using the `<>` in the editor. Then it will show and active snippet (and if there's errors you'll get a message — though not a helpful one).

Comment: `getElementByClassName` doesn't exists. Right syntax is `getElementsByClassName`and it will return an `HTMLCollection` so right syntax is  `var num1 = document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0]`. Same with `changeIt`. Then you have to bind an `onmouseout` event  on `num1` to handle the hiding

Comment: thanks diouze, I don't understand the [0] part, however. Isn't the "top" class in the [0] position of the sidebar class? Should I, rather, put ('sidebar') [0]?

Comment: Because each <li> has a separate class I mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show/hide a div on hover and hover out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114543/show-hide-a-div-on-hover-and-hover-out)

Answer (score 0):

do this with CSS only, not javascript, using the

> :hover

selector in combination with

> ::after

plus

```
visibility:hidden;
```

[documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

example

```
.topb {
    position:absolute;
    top:140px;
    left:420px;
    color:black;
    border:2px solid black;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.topb:hover::after {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

I use this in my website [www.mr-programs.com](http://www.mr-programs.com) on the button on the very beginning, if u hover it, some animations trigger.

Answer (score 0):

1st:

There is no any api like `document.getElementByClassName`, maybe u wanna use this  [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName),

2nd:

Even api is right, one thing should take care is it `Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.`

3nd:

if your code run in modern browser, i recommend u use this api [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) because of it is really simple. but if it run in older browser, may `jQuery` is a good choose.

1. modern browser:

   ```
   var num1 = document.querySelector(".top"); // `dot means it is a className
   ```
2. pure JavaScript:

   ```
   var num1 = document.getElementsByClassName(".top")[0]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

num1.onmouseover = function() {.....}

```js
var num1 = document.getElementByClassName("top");
num1.onmouseover = function() {
var changeIt = getElementByClassName("topb");
if (changeIt.style.visibility === "hidden") {
changeIt.style.visibility = "visible";
}else {
changeIt.style.visibility = "hidden";
};
```

**or**

num1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    ...
});

```
var num1 = document.getElementByClassName("top");    
num1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    var changeIt = getElementByClassName("topb");
    if (changeIt.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    changeIt.style.visibility = "visible";
    }else {
    changeIt.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```